# Duplicate methods named update with the parameters (T) and (T) are inherited from the types B<AbstractEntity> and A<AbstractEntity>

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes. B extends from A and C extends from B. In that case i got an duplicate methods error. How can I avoid this error?

I need this two top levels and i dont want to combine them in one class.

```
 public abstract class A<T extends AbstractBaseEntity> implements Serializable {

    protected T update(final T entity) {
        final EntityManager entityMgr = getEntityManager();

        final T result = entityMgr.merge(entity);
        entityMgr.flush();
        entityMgr.refresh(result);
        return result;

    }
}

public abstract class B <T extends AbstractEntity> extends A<AbstractEntity> {

    public B() {
        super();
    }

    protected T update(final T entity) {
        // Some other validations
        return (T) super.update(entity);
    }

}

public class C extends B<AbstractEntity> {


    public C() {
        super();
    }

}
```

[image]

P.S: AbstractEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity

Comment: Didn't you mean `public abstract class B <T extends AbstractEntity> extends A<T>` ?

Comment: shouldn't it be `B<T extends AbstractEntity> extends A<T>`? rats, @assylias beat me to it.

Comment: @assylias Actually not. Should it be ?

Comment: @Kayser is your `update` method in B supposed to override the method in A? If yes then cf my previous comment, if not then it is quite confusing: which method should be called on `B<AbstractEntity>.update()`?

Comment: @assylias Yes, it adds some other validations

Comment: @Kayser: why did you delete your previous, identical question, where I already gave you an answer?

Comment: @Kayser at the moment the method in B is not overriding the method in A. You can add an `@Override` annotation to verify it.

Comment: @assylias because of the generic it does not allow to add override annotation.

Comment: @Kayser It does not allow to add override because B's method ***is not*** overriding A's method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem a little confused. At the moment, the `update` method in B does not override the `update` method in A because they don't have the same signature.

What you want is the generic type of B and A to be the same, so that `update(T)` means the same thing in both classes. This is easily solved by declaring your B class as follows:

```
public abstract class B <T extends AbstractEntity> extends A<T>
```

By the way it is good practice to use the `@Override` annotation, which you can place before your `update` method in B. It will show you that in your current version you are not overriding the parent method.

Now, a `B<T>` is also an `A<T>` (whereas in your version, a `B<T>` is an `A<AbstractEntity>`).